# friendly urls like facebook

Tags: facebook, url

how can I  rewrite my url like facebook does .

(https://www.facebook.com/user_name )

if i pass http://example.com/profile.php?id=username  to http://example.com/username , i will no be able to use "?" after username => http://example.com/username?ajaxify=1

Answer (score 1):

This is usually achieved using URL rewriting using the mod_rewrite in Apache. You need to set redirect rules in your .htaccess file in your application root.

You can readmore about rewrite rules with thia guide https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: but if i rewrite i'm not abble to use ?= again

Comment: but ir i wewrite i cant use this :  http://example.com/username?ajaxify=1  => i will need use http://example.com/username&ajaxify=1

Comment: If the rules are written correctly it will work because this is simply rewrite, whereas your old urls point to actual resources on the server.

Comment: If you go through the rewrite rules carefully you will find that you can rewrite portions of the url

Answer (score 0):

Search more about mod rewrite on htaccess
For example:
http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

thanks to everyone

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes

<IfModule mod_php4.c> 
    php_flag register_globals Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c> 
    php_flag allow_url_include Off
    php_flag register_globals Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search/tag/([^/.]+)/{0,1}$  search.php?Tags=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^browse/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ browse.php?sex=$1&age=$2&country=$3 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^m/(.*)$  modules/index.php?r=$1 [QSA,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ profile.php?ID=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```